# What can I use to clean the rim and inside of my metal snare drum?

Tags: drums, maintenance

I have fantastic all purpose cleaner. Can I use that to clean the inside and outside as well as the rim of my snare drum (not including the non metal head)?

Answer (score 4):

I guess what you need to do is look at what metal the drum and rim are made for, and then look at the cleaner instructions to see if it can be used on that metal.

If you can't find that information I would suggest trying a very small area on a part of the drum that isn't visible and see how it reacts.

Answer (score 2):

Windex has never failed me for this.

If there is any built up gunk, a small amount of metal polish and a soft cloth does the trick.  Very fine steel wool as well if it's really bad.